# Dynamically allocate ragged matrix

Tags: c++, generics, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm trying to make a generic function which will dynamically allocate 2D structure. Number of elements in every row doesn't have to be same for all rows. Structure is represented as a container type, whose elements are again of a container type (for example a set of lists). The type of elements of that inner container can also be arbitrary. Containers only support the begin, end, and size functions. Iterator operations must be supported for all iterator types. The function should first dynamically allocate the space for storing the 2D structure by the continuous allocation procedure, and then rewrite the elements of the structure it has accepted into the dynamic structure. The function returns a double pointer through which the elements of this structure can be accessed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
template < typename tip >
  auto Make2DStructure(tip mat) {
    using tip_objekta = typename std::decay < decltype(mat[0][0]) > ::type;
    tip_objekta ** dynamic_mat = nullptr;
    int rows = 0, total = 0;
    for (auto i: mat) {
      rows++;
      for (auto j: i)
        total++;
    }
    int columns[rows];
    int k = 0;
    for (auto i: mat) {
      int num_of_colums = 0;
      for (auto j: i)
        num_of_colums++;
      columns[k] = num_of_colums;
      k++;
    }

    try {
      dynamic_mat = new tip_objekta * [rows];
      dynamic_mat[0] = new tip_objekta[total];
      for (int i = 1; i < rows; i++)
        dynamic_mat[i] = dynamic_mat[i - 1] + columns[i];
      for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < columns[i]; j++)
          dynamic_mat[i][j] = mat[i][j];
    } catch (...) {
      delete[] dynamic_mat[0];
      delete[] dynamic_mat;
      throw std::bad_alloc();
    }
    return dynamic_mat;
  }

int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>>mat{
        {1,2},
        {3,4,5,6},
        {7,8,9}
    };
    int columns[3]={2,4,3};
  try {
    int ** dynamic_mat = Make2DStructure(mat);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < columns[i]; j++)
        std::cout << dynamic_mat[i][j] << " ";
      std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    delete[] dynamic_mat[0];
    delete[] dynamic_mat;
  } catch (...) {
    std::cout << "Problems with memory";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

How could I modify this to work without indexing inside `Make2DStrucure()`?

Also, if I used `std::set<std::list<int>>` instead of `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` in main function I would have deduction problems. How could I modify this to work for different outside and inside container?

Comment: This sounds exactly like `std::vector<std::vector<T>>`. Have you tried using that?

Comment: It could be deque of lists, or vector of vector, but the point is that I don't know which container types they will be. The function is generic

Comment: Ok, then perhaps I misunderstood. What's the reason for returning a raw _pointer-pointer_ instead of something that manages the lifetime for you automatically?

Comment: that is the task setting, double pointer is used because of dynamic allocation

Comment: Do what is required of you by the assigner (if this is for professional work, do what you can to talk them out of it) but know that passing around raw pointers is not how you should manage dynamic allocations in modern C++ (or any C++ after Standardization in 1998).

Comment: thanks, but have you noticed that I have some problems inside the code? I accept that double pointer is not good choice, but I cannot compile this because of problems of deduction type. If I used vector of vector in main function I wouldn't have deduction problems, but in both cases I don't know how to count rows and columns of ragged matrix.

Comment: I have edited code, now it works for vector of vector. How could I modify this to work for set of lists or deque of list, or deque of vectors? container types only support std::begin(), std::end(), and size() functions

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you need. Does [this](https://godbolt.org/z/vT5qod6qT) do it?

Comment: it gives correct result, but I don't know have you used continual allocation for this? If yes, could you post it as answer with some comments? Also, I'm using C++14, so could you modify it for C++14?

Comment: @Ted : see if you can use `std::begin` so you can also rope in raw arrays.

Comment: @user4581301 Good idea: https://godbolt.org/z/ejjjrWGjK

Comment: @TedLyngmo if this is continual allocation, could you post answer in C++14 with some comments?

Comment: @RocketProcd Ok, I posted a C++14 version with comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to accomplish what you want:

```cpp
#include <iterator>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename tip>
auto Make2DStructure(tip&& mat) {
    // create an alias for the value type:
    using value_type = std::decay_t<decltype(*std::begin(*std::begin(mat)))>;

    // allocate memory for the return value, the pointer-pointer:    
    value_type** rv = new value_type*[mat.size()]; // C++17: std::size(mat)

    // Calculate the number of values we need to allocate space for:
    size_t values = 0;
    for(auto& inner: mat) values += inner.size();  // C++17: std::size(inner)
    
    // allocate the space for the values:
    value_type* data = new value_type[values];

    // loop over the outer and inner container and keep the index running:   
    size_t idx = 0;

    for(auto& inner : mat) {
        // assign the outer pointer into the flat data block:
        rv[idx++] = data;
        for(auto& val : inner) {
            // assign values in the data block:
            *data++ = val;
        }
    }

    return rv;
}
```

With the use of `std::size` where indicated, this would work with plain arrays too, not only the container classes.

Comment: you one thing, indexing inside Make2DStructure() doesn't have to be supported, is there any way to modify this using iterators instead of indexing?

Comment: @RocketProcd Right now the knowledge about the sizes of each "inner" array is lost in the translation to the `int**` format but I guess one could create a special iterator type for this particular setup. You would have to at least supply some information to the `end` iterator for the outer array though. It can't be deduced from the information stored in the `int**`.

Comment: is there any way to reduce this `std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<
        decltype(*std::begin(*std::begin(std::declval<tip>())))>>;` ?

Comment: @RocketProcd You could use the actual instance instead of `std::declval<tip>()` which would shorten it down to `std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<         decltype(*std::begin(*std::begin(mat)))>>;` - You could also use the `begin()` member functions instead of `std::begin()` since you require the `size()` member function anyway. If you could use C++17, I would have used `std::size(mat)` instead of `mat.size()` to be able to send in plain arrays too but then I'd need to add a `size` function template to provide the same functionality.

Comment: thanks, that's at least a little less

Comment: I found another way `using value_type = typename std::decay<decltype(*std::begin(*std::begin(mat)))>::type;`

Comment: @RocketProcd Oh, yes, that actually falls back to `std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t< ...` so that'll work fine. You can even use the `std::decay_t` helper in C++14 to make it shorter. I updated the answer.